# Do neutrino produce gravitational wave?

Tags: gravitational-waves, neutrinos

Neutrino can oscillates and it's mass fluctuate according to which of the three known flavors, since it has mass and is known to change flavors in flight... now more mind blogging stuff is the particle is in superposition states and my question is does it produce gravitational wave however weak?

Comment: No offence intended, but why would being in a superposition of states affect things (more or less than any other particle with mass  in a superposition of states ?) If it has mass, why would it not have a gravitational wave production capability?

Comment: @Countto10: none taken as I'm also trying to learn physics like every beginner and I remember reading that gravitational wave carry energy and so if neutrino can lose energy via gravitational wave things get complicated for me I'm so confused.

Comment: All particles are weird :) And your last line? If you are not confused, you ain't trying....best of luck with your studies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In General Relativity, the variation of spacetime curvature is induced by variations of energy and momentum. The energy and momentum of a neutrino oscillating between two flavours does not change. Hence this is no different from a particle which would not oscillate in that manner. The energy-momentum of the neutrinos could have an effect on spacetime curvature of course, as any other particles. Although for the specific question of gravitational waves, the conditions on energy-momentum variation are pretty strict but this is another question.